# How to optimize repeat MySQL sorted selects

Tags: mysql, sorting, optimization, indexing, sql-order-by

Suppose that I have a large db with columns a, b, and c.  Suppose that I then wish to select the xth through (x+100)th rows according to some ordering on multiple columns.  I can accomplish this using the  `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` constructs:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY b ASC, c DESC, a DESC LIMIT x, 100
```

What if I then wish to conduct many similar queries using the same order (ascending on b, descending on c, then descending on a) but with different range limits?  Intuitively, the costly sorting operation shouldn't need to be repeated for each such query.

I've looking into optimizing `ORDER BY` operations using indices (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html), but unfortunately it does not seem possible to create indicies that include mixed ascending and descending orders.

Is there a good approach to optimizing this?  It seems like a reasonably common use case.

Comment: FYI, the syntax would be `LIMIT x, 100` -- it's `LIMIT start, count`, not `LIMIT start, end`.

Comment: Is the `b` column the only one that has a different direction than the others? If yes, is by any chance the `b` column numeric?

Comment: What are the datatypes of both `b` and `c`?  Can we get a clue of their semantics?  (date, ranking, username, ...)

Comment: @s3v3n For my actual application I'll sometimes have more than just three columns, and there will be an arbitrary assignment of ascending and descending orders.

Comment: @RickJames I am specifically looking at an application where all the columns are numeric (specifically MySQL's `DOUBLE` type).  However, I'm interested in learning a solution to the more general case as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the only optimization is to have a numeric `b` either stored as `-b` or have an extra column that redundantly has `-b` in it.  Then

```
ORDER BY b ASC, c DESC LIMIT...
```

would be replaced by

```
ORDER BY minusb DESC, c DESC LIMIT...
```

And have

```
INDEX(minusb, c)
```

As long as you make sure that

- all of the `ORDER BY` items are column names in the same table,
- with the same direction,
- and an `INDEX` exists that lists all of them in the same order as the `ORDER BY` list (optionally extra columns on the *end*),

then the optimizer *can* (but may choose not to) use that `INDEX` very effectively -- including consuming the `LIMIT`.

It does not matter whether you make all of them `ASC` or all of them `DESC`.  (`ASC` *might* be slightly better.)

Keep in mind that `LIMIT m, n` will have to read `m+n` rows.  (`OFFSET` is a nice feature, but it is not well optimized.)  If you are "paginating" through a long list using `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`, it is better to "remember where you left off" to avoid scanning over the `OFFSET` rows.  (If this applies, I can give you more details.)

Comment: Oh wow, same idea, but your might be better for using negative value instead of `MAX - x`. Good job!

Comment: All `DOUBLEs` are negatable, except maybe NaNs.  `INT UNSIGNED` would need some trick like `maxint - x`.  `INT SIGNED` is unlikely to be in trouble, unless you happen to currently have the max negative number.  (For example, `TINYINT SIGNED` ranges from -128 to +127, so -128 cannot be negated.)

Comment: `DECIMALs` are always negatable.

Comment: Thanks for the idea!  On a separate note, I am indeed paginating a long list.  I'd love it if you could point me towards details about approaches that avoid re-scanning the `OFFSET` rows.

Comment: [My pagination blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) discusses why and how to "remember where you left off".

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea (which is rather a hack) that might work for numeric columns.
For every column that you want to sort by, add a new column of the same type which will have the value `MAX_TYPE - column_value`, where `MAX_TYPE` is the maximum value expected for this column. Now add an index to this column and sort by it instead of the original column.

**Heads up:**

- I've used `DECIMAL` instead of `DOUBLE` as double might have rounding errors.
- Perhaps I'm missing something because `MySQL` doesn't use any index at all when using `ORDER BY` (even by a single column).
- The solution suggested by @Rick James it's definitely better than using a `MAX_TYPE`.

[SQL fiddle:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2767/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE `bogus` (
  `income` DECIMAL(7,2),
  `expense` DECIMAL(7,2),
  `expense_inverted` DECIMAL(7,2)
);

ALTER TABLE `bogus` ADD INDEX `income_idx` (`income`);
ALTER TABLE `bogus` ADD INDEX `expense_idx` (`expense`);
ALTER TABLE `bogus` ADD INDEX `expense_inverted_idx` (`expense_inverted`);

INSERT INTO `bogus` (`income`, `expense`)
  VALUES
  (250.35, 200.90),
  (250.35, 100.35),
  (300.50, 210.75);

UPDATE `bogus` SET `expense_inverted` = 99999.99 - `expense`;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT income, expense
FROM `bogus`
ORDER BY
  `income` ASC,
  `expense_inverted` ASC; # equivalent of `expense` DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2767/1/0)**:

```
| income | expense |
|--------|---------|
| 250.35 |   200.9 |
| 250.35 |  100.35 |
|  300.5 |  210.75 |
```

I understand that this is a very inelegant solution, but for large databases where you cannot sacrifice speed - this might work.

Comment: For sorting on a single column, you are certainly right.  The index can be traversed in either forwards or backwards order.  However, when using an index on multiple columns I believe that this is not the case.

Comment: From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html: "In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the `ORDER BY`... These cases include the following: You mix `ASC` and `DESC` example: `SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY key_part1 DESC, key_part2 ASC`"

Comment: OK, you're right, I didn't know about this. I'm deleting my answer.

Comment: It is a hack, but it's a good idea in certain situations.  Thanks!